# For loop is not looping through elements

Tags: java, arrays, nodes

I am trying to parse values from my XML ( images and text) but this code is just returning the same value over and over again when i want to return each separate value in the application. Can anyone tell me how to do this? When I try to run (i) through it i get this error When i try that code it throws this error :
   Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.shannon.dogs/com.example.shannon.dogs.ActivityOne}:    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method '  org.w3c.dom.Node org.w3c.dom.Node.getFirstChild()' on a null object reference –

```
    NodeList nameNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");
    NodeList originNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("origin");
    NodeList colorNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("color");
    NodeList imageNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("image");
    NodeList heightNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("height");
    NodeList weightNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("weight");
    NodeList groomingNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("grooming");
    //NodeList infoNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("info");
    NodeList lifespanNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("lifespan");
    NodeList urlNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("url");


        //create data
        data = new Dog[nameNodeList.getLength()];
       for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          data[i] = new Dog(
                nameNodeList.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
                originNodeList.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
                colorNodeList.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
                imageNodeList.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
                heightNodeList.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
                weightNodeList.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
                groomingNodeList.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
                lifespanNodeList.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
                urlNodeList.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
        //infoNodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),  //);
    }
```

Comment: This is a simple for loop logic, you need to try a little bit before asking such questions.

Comment: Please view my edited question - I get errors every time i try to run(i) through it.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't iterating through them. You're just looking at the first element. Try changing the 0's to i's to be inline with your `for` loop

```
data = new Dog[nameNodeList.getLength()];
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = new Dog(
            nameNodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
            originNodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
            colorNodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
            imageNodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
            heightNodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
            weightNodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
            groomingNodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
            lifespanNodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
            urlNodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    //infoNodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),  //);
}
```

Comment: When i try that code it throws this error : Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shannon.dogs/com.example.shannon.dogs.ActivityOne}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'org.w3c.dom.Node org.w3c.dom.Node.getFirstChild()' on a null object reference

Comment: According to the documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getFirstChild()) - The first child of this node. If there is no such node, this returns null. You may have to alter your other code to accommodate that.